# Add buttons to libnotify notifications that run functions

Tags: c++, libnotify

I need to add buttons to the bottom of a libnotify notification that run functions when clicked. I can make the buttons appear, but they don't run the functions when clicked. It gives no error message at all.

The program is called with `./notifications "Title" "Body" "pathtoicon"`

Code:

```
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <iostream>

void callback_mute(NotifyNotification* n, char* action, gpointer user_data) {
  std::cout << "Muting Program" << std::endl;
  system("pkexec kernel-notify -am");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    GError *error = NULL;
    notify_init("Basics");
    NotifyNotification* n = notify_notification_new (argv[1],
                                 argv[2],
                                 argv[3]);

    notify_notification_add_action (n,
      "action_click",
      "Mute",
       NOTIFY_ACTION_CALLBACK(callback_mute),
       NULL,
       NULL);


    notify_notification_set_timeout(n, 10000);
    if (!notify_notification_show(n, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Notification failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `GMainLoop`, a "main event loop" in order for the callback function to work. `libnotify` uses this loop in order to handle its actions, without it, it simply doesn't call the callback function you expected as there's nothing handling it.

Basically in your `main` function, just add a `GMainLoop *loop` in the beginning then `loop = g_main_loop_new(nullptr, FALSE);` to initialize it after that, then in the end just add `g_main_loop_run(loop);`. Your program should run just like as before but the callback function working now. So basically:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  loop = g_main_loop_new(nullptr, FALSE);
  // ... do your stuff
  g_main_loop_run(loop);
  return 0;
}
```

You can read more about it at: [The Main Event Loop: GLib Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)

You don't have to include `glib.h` as `libnotify` includes it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this later and respond